# Hora incorrecta en el siguiente codigo usando Moment.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, momentjs

HTML dentro del row, esta la columna 'date_created' que se encuentra en mi base de datos

```
<td class="created_at align-middle font-weight-bold text-center"><?php echo date('r',strtotime($row['date_created'])) ?></td>
```

JS

```
$('.created_at').each(function(){
    $date = $(this).html();

    $mydate = moment.utc($date).local().format('lll');

    $(this).html($mydate);
});
```

El problema aqui es que me devuelve la hora mal, actualmente tengo las 12:21PM, pero me lanza 11:21AM, cuando cambio la hora de mi sistema tambien cambia la fecha y hora en la aplicacion pero sigue teniendo ese error en la hora con una menos de diferencia siempre.

Comment: no funciono aun

Comment: Prueba con `echo date('h:i A',strtotime($row['date_created']))` y/o también con `$mydate = moment.utc($date).local().format('h:mm A');`

Answer (score 0):

prueba usando algunos de los siguientes formatos

```javascript
let hora1 = moment($date).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
console.log(hora1);
let hora2 = moment($date).format('lll');
console.log(hora2);
let hora3 = moment($date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
console.log(hora3);
```

el problema probablemente lo tenes porque estas formateando el tiempo en `UTC` y con la hora local de tu maquina pueda ser que tenga una diferencia en la zona horaria.

Comment: Aun sigue arrojando la misma hora.

Comment: la hora que le insertas como parametro es formato UTC?.

Comment: Asi es, solo capturo Horas y minutos con la respectiva fecha actual

Answer (score 0):

El problema era en que nuestro localhost estaba con la hora incorrecta, en el lado de produccion se muestra correctamente, ya que esta hosteado en otra parte del mundo, Esta resuelto problema, gracias a los que colaboraron...